# Ciclo de vida e as variáveis react (state and useEffect)

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

Estou com problemas a entender o ciclo de vida do React.

**Resumo do projeto:** O React vai buscar informações numa API repetidamente (`setInterval`) com determinados filtros, em que os filtros também são resultado de um request à API.

Existem `stations`, `orders` e `currentStation` (que vem da UI).

O meu problema é que quando se faz `dispatch` para definir uma variável, não é possível fazer logo o `get` dessa mesma variável.

Segue algumas partes do meu componente:

```
useEffect(() => {
    listStations().then(() => {
        dispatch({type: 'setLoadedStations', state: true});
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    listOrders(true);
}, [state.loadedStations]);

const listOrders = async (createJob?: boolean) => {
    let currentStationId = state.stations[state.currentStation].id;
    const orderList = await getOrders(currentStationId); 
    dispatch({type: 'setOrders', value: orderList});

    if(createJob) {
        setInterval(await listOrders, 4000);
    }
}


return (
  <IonButton
    onClick={
        (e: any) => {
            e.persist();
            dispatch({
                type: 'setCurrentStation',
                station: key
            });
        }
    }
  >
    {station.title}
  </IonButton>
);
```

No `setInterval` vai sempre ser o mesmo `state.currentStation` onde o `setInterval` foi criado. Mesmo que mais tarde o `currentStation` mude.

Outra solução que tentei foi adicionar um *clear*, mas também não resultou porque a variável não é 'guarda'.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
let jobId = 0;

if(createJob) {
    if(jobId) clearInterval(jobId);
    jobId = setInterval(await listOrders, 4000);
}
```

Qual a forma correcta? Aceder a uma variável state sem um `useEffect` é possível?

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa demais, e chamar `listOrders` sem colocá-la como dependência do `useEffect` é um erro. Precisa de uma refatoração aí.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As variáveis de estado ficam desatualizadas por causa do funcionamento do closure, sugiro que leia algum artigo sobre isso para que entenda melhor o funcionamento.

Não entendi inteiramente a sua questão, mas vou deixar uma solução relacionada a manter o valor de um estado atualizado dentro de uma função chamada em um setInterval.

Consiste em manter os estados usados dentro do setInterval atualizados incluindo estes estados no array de dependências do useEffect, recomendo que você execute este exemplo para entender melhor o funcionamento:

```
const useTimer = (filter) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Criando novo interval");
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(`Chamou função com o valor: ${filter}`);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      console.log("Valor do filter foi alterado, limpando interval");
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, [filter]);
};

const ComponentePai = () => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("1");
  useTimer(filter);

  return (
    <select
      onChange={(e) => {
        setFilter(e.target.value);
      }}
    >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sim, isso esta correcto. Eu entretanto, entendi o verdadeiro potencial dos hooks e como criar os meus próprios useFunctions.
Marquei como aceite a sua resposta de forma a poder ajudar futuramente novas pessoas no react.